# SQL to retrieve tree structure nicely

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, tree

Given the simple data structure:

```
ID    |    Category_Name    |    Parent_ID
```

Example:

```
1          Cars                    0
2          Boxes                   0
3          Lamborghinis            1
4          VW Camper Vans          1
5          Big Boxes               2
6          Small Boxes             2
7          Cereal Boxes            2
8          Broken Lambos           3
9          Yellow Ones             3
10         Rusty                   8
11         Milkshake Stained       8
12         Chocolate Flavour       11
13         Strawberry              11
14         Indiscernible Solution  11
```

Representing a simple tree navigation structure, what would programatically be the best way to retrieve the tree in a presentable format?  Can we create an SQL statement to retrieve them 'in order'?

Thanks for any help!  If my approach is wrong, feel free to comment also.

I'm using SQL-Server 2000.

Comment: What is the database platform? A number of the common SQL solutions are platform specific.

Comment: What Database are you using? If its MS-SQL 2005 and above, have you looked at Recursive CTE's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 you might want to try out the new [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) data type.

If you're not then another way is to look into the [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) model which works on all databases.

If you're using SQL Server 2005 and up you can use [recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to retreive the tree structure.

Comment: then the only way is to use a while loop, insert into temp table and return those back.

i'd urge you to look into the nested sets model, though.

Answer (score 2):

I usually build the tree structure in my application code. Partially because I'm more confident with c# than SQL, but it also because I usually need to process the data into suitable c# structures anyway.

SQL is quite bad at recursive structures like lists and trees. If I had to put the tree building in my database I'd go for a stored procedure. But there might be a smart way I don't know about.

If you use Oracle you might be able to hack something up with [Connect By](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html).

Answer (score 2):

Not for SQL2000, but if you manage to upgrade to 2k5, you can do

```
WITH t AS(SELECT id, parent_id, category_name FROM mytable WHERE parent_id IS NULL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.category_name FROM t p JOIN mytable c ON c.parent_id = p.id)
SELECT * FROM t
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting!  Is it possible for that to be broken down at all to work in SQL 2000 do you think?