# Is it possible write this query without using cursor

Tags: mysql

I have already written above logic using c# code but I want to handle it at database query level as optimization.

I am using mysql database The schema of department is

```
    Department Table
Deptid     DeptName ParentDeptid
1          CEO        -  
2          HR         1
3          IT         1
4          Dev        3
5          QA         3
6          clerk      5

Employee table
Empid    EmpName   deptid
1        E1            1
2        E2            2
3        E3            3
4        E4            4
5        E5            4
6        E6            4
7        E7            5
8        E8            5
9        E9            5
10       E10           6
```

I need output as if I have selected deptid is 3
I want all descendent of dept 3. 
It means for dept id 3

```
deptid  parentdept  count
3       1           1
4       3           3
5       3           3
6       5           1
```

Comment: Question is unclear: If you select `deptid = 2` how are you expecting to get rows with `deptid` 3, 4 or 5 as of your first sample output table? Which other constraint should fire?

Comment: Furthermore: your last example should have the column `DeptName` and `ParentDeptName` or it is wrong allover.

Comment: Extremely Sorry I have updated question.

Comment: After edit: This row `3       1           1` doesn't fit as deptid 3 is not a descendant of itself and has a parent of 1 as all of the other actually have 3

Comment: I need deptid 3 also in output

Comment: Then please refine your verbal constraint, otherwise that doesn't make sense. Like "`get me all rows where id = x or parentid = x`" or something else

Comment: You may have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555101/sql-to-retrieve-tree-structure-nicely

Comment: It is for mssql not mysql

Comment: Way, the OP states using "`SQL Server 2000`" and the Q is tagged "`sql-server`" - what's the diff between SQL Server and MS SQL ... ?

Comment: no sql server and mssql are same but I am using mysql database