# SQL Select Query for organization tree (hierarchy)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TH_ORGANIZATION]
(
    [ID_CORGANIZATION] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CCOMPANY] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CORGANIZATION_NAME_tr] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CORGANIZATION_NAME_en] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CORGANIZATION_MAN_ID_CEMP] [decimal](10, 0) NULL,
    [CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [CACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TH_ORGANIZATION_CACTIVE]  DEFAULT ((1)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TH_ORGANIZATION] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_CORGANIZATION] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now I want to write a SQL query for getting my organization tree. The main column is `ID_CORGANIZATION` and the sub organziation connected with `CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID` column with the same table.

Any ideas?

---

Now best solution is

```
 WITH temp as(SELECT * FROM TH_ORGANIZATION WHERE ID_CORGANIZATION = '3'  UNION ALL SELECT ei.* FROM TH_ORGANIZATION ei INNER JOIN temp x ON ei.CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID = x.ID_CORGANIZATION ") SELECT * FROM temp
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to retrieve tree structure nicely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555101/sql-to-retrieve-tree-structure-nicely)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TH_ORGANIZATION As O,
    TH_ORGANIZATION As Sub
WHERE O.ID_CORGANIZATION 
    = Sub.CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID;
```

You will get a list of Organization with its sub organizations, recursive. Of course you can order the list, too.

If you want all under one column you can use an outer join like this (so select only O.*):

```
SELECT O.* FROM th_organization As O
LEFT OUTER JOIN th_organization As Sub
ON O.id_corganization 
    = Sub.corganization_uplink_id;
```

Example (I use abbreviations), you should get this kind of list:

```
id_c uplink_id  name
  1             OrgA
  2             OrgB 
 11      1      subA
 12      1      subB
 21      2      sub2
111     11      subsubA
```

Comment: Your query is not suit for me. My best query is "WITH temp as(SELECT * FROM TH_ORGANIZATION WHERE ID_CORGANIZATION = '3'  UNION ALL 
            SELECT ei.* FROM TH_ORGANIZATION ei INNER JOIN temp x ON ei.CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID = x.ID_CORGANIZATION 
             ) SELECT * FROM temp‏
            sql += @" WHERE ID_CCOMPANY=@idCompany ";
            sql += @" ORDER BY CORGANIZATION_SORTNO";

Answer (score 0):

My best solution that I find :

```
WITH temp as(SELECT * FROM TH_ORGANIZATION WHERE ID_CORGANIZATION = '3'  UNION ALL SELECT ei.* FROM TH_ORGANIZATION ei INNER JOIN temp x ON ei.CORGANIZATION_UPLINK_ID = x.ID_CORGANIZATION ") SELECT * FROM temp
```

Note: '3' my started organization id