# How to code organizational structure in hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, hana

I am building a structural dimension in a data analysis software. This structure should reflect the Organizational Structure. 
The hierarchy is as follows:

1. Business Unit
2. Department
3. Department
4. Department 
   (possibly more)

The departments are related in a parent/child-relationship.
The data table has the following columns:

- Business Unit
- Business Unit (Label)
- Department
- Department Label
- Parent Department
- Parent Department Label

I just do not know how to set up this code to create the parent/child relationship while also grouping to the correct Business Unit.

I will also be using joins to link employees to the corresponding departments, which I would happily accept advice on how to do. 
Thanks :-)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data would also help.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which database engine are you using, such as MySQL, Oracle, or Microsoft SQL Server. Thanks.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148496/sql-select-query-for-organization-tree-hierarchy (SQL Server).

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query (MySQL)

Comment: Sorry all. Added database now

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, what I would have done is :

- BusinessUnit (PK, BULabel)
- Department (PK, BusinessUnitPK,ParentDepartmentPK, DLabel)
- Check(BusinessUnitPK is null xor ParentDepartmentPK is null)  : integrity check so that a departement "inherits" the business unit
- Employe(PK,DepartmentPK)